# Is ForceAuthn=true good idea for Service Provider

Tags: security, authentication, saml-2.0

Looking for guidance to understand the use case behind `ForceAuthn=true` for SAML-driven Single Sign-On.

We know that `ForceAuthn=true` will always challenge the user for credentials which creates friction thus negative experience for the user.

However, that's UX story. What about security?

If `ForceAuthn=false`, I authenticate once and the second time a seamless login will happen.

This might create an issue where unware user using public PC can leave the access open for the next person.

If you have are (or work) for a provider (e.g. SaaS) and have SAML-driven SSO with clients, what is your policy/experience around this topic?

Answer (score 2):

It's not common for service providers to set `ForceAuthn=true`. As the service provider, it's not your decision on how to authenticate a user when you are entrusting that process to the identity provider. And, what happens when the IdP is using a non-interactive authentication mechanism like Kerberos? While they may see the redirects occurring, there's no user interaction with or without forcing authentication. Point being, if you're outsourcing authn, then outsource it, and then have the IdP indemnify you for anything around authentication.

What I do see service providers doing is using `ForceAuthn=true` to use as "singular transaction authorization" like for authorization of steps in workflows and digital signing.

Comment: Thanks, @andrew-k, good points. What about a situation where the user does SSO from e.g. holiday hotel, clicks Remember Me, closes the browser. In theory, a next person could click on the link via history and be dropped into service whit out being challenged for credentials. Risk/no-risk? Should SP care about that?

Comment: Sorry, missed your response. In my opinion, this is not your issue to resolve. You don't own the authentication. You own a service that depends on authentication elsewhere. If your Identity Providers choose to not care about about the users they authenticate, then that's on them... And, your legal department should make that very clear to your IdP partners as part of your service's contracts. They want the convenience of SSO, which requires them to **own** authentication from soup to nuts, including bad actors getting in through the authentication process somehow.